# Extract 2 specific imagery bands from a list of landsat tar.gz

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, extract, landsat

I Have a list of Landsat scenes. Inside of tar.gz are multiple bands. Like:

File "*LC08018051date.tar.gz*"

> LC08_date_sr_band1.tif
>   LC08_date_sr_band2.tif
>   LC08_date_sr_band3.tif
>   LC08_date_sr_band4.tif
>   LC08_date_sr_band5.tif
>   LC08_date_sr_band6.tif
>   LC08_date_sr_band7.tif

I need to extract only `LC08_date_sr_band3.tif` and `LC08_date_sr_band4.tif` to calculate an index.

This code works  extracting all "band" from all files.

```
import tarfile
import os
import glob
files = glob.glob('L*.tar.gz')
for fileName in files:
    tfile = tarfile.open(fileName, 'r:gz')
    membersList = tfile.getmembers()
    namesList = tfile.getnames()
    bandsList = [x for x, y in zip(membersList, namesList) if "sr_band" in y]
    print("extracting...")
    tfile.extractall("Folder/",members=bandsList)
    print ("Done")
```

The thing is i need extract only sr_band3 and sr_band4

Comment: Good question. I would like to know yet.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best option but what i do is:

```
import tarfile
import os
import glob
import re
files = glob.glob('L*.tar.gz')
if not files: 
   raise Exception('No se han encontrado archivos a procesar')
for fileName in files:
    tfile = tarfile.open(fileName, 'r:gz')
    membersList = tfile.getmembers()
    namesList = tfile.getnames()
    bandsList = [x for x, y in zip(membersList, namesList) if "sr_band3" in y]
    print("extracting...")
    tfile.extractall("bands/",members=bandsList)
    print ("Done")
for fileName in files:
    tfile = tarfile.open(fileName, 'r:gz')
    membersList = tfile.getmembers()
    namesList = tfile.getnames()
    bandsList = [x for x, y in zip(membersList, namesList) if "sr_band4" in y]
    print("extracting...")
    tfile.extractall("bands/",members=bandsList)
    print ("Done")
```

The code enter each time to the file, so is not the fastest way.